# Firebase Push Notifications with jQuery (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am attempting to send a push notification from a simple test webpage. I am using firebase. This is my current code:

```
function sendPushNotification() {
    $.ajax({        
        type : 'POST',
        url : "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        headers : {
            Authorization : 'key=' + '<my_server_key>',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"notification": {"body":"Test"}}),
        success : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);                   
        }
    });
}
```

I get the error:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (HTTP/2.0 400) (send, line 0)
```

Which I am assuming is a bad request. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream), a 400 error is returned when the JSON in your request can't be parsed. If you check the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#preview) in your browser, you should be able to see the exact failure reason.

Please note that FCM messages shouldn't be sent from the client. Sending messages requires:

> A trusted environment such as Cloud Functions for Firebase or an app
>   server on which to build, target and send messages.
>   (*[FCM docs: How does it work?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/#how_does_it_work)*)

Comment: Do you know the correct call though? (I know that they shouldn't be send from client, but this is for testing)

Comment: Have you checked your network tab to see what the error is? You may want to also check there to see what your request looks like.